# What does this doctrine error compilation mean?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Here is my controller :

```
$something = $this->get("myManager")->getAll();
        return $this->render('pathToTemplate/myTemplate.html.twig', [
            'something' => $something,
        ]);
```

Here is my manager :

```
return $this->em->getRepository(Something::class)->findBy(array('xxx'=>false));
```

I've this error :

> Compile Error: Doctrine\Common\Proxy\Autoloader::Doctrine\Common\Proxy{closure}(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\pathToProject\var\cache\dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies__CG__MyBundleMyEntity.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

But `myEntity.php` was removed and `Something.php` doesn't have any relation with it.

I've tried :

> cache:clear
>
> cache:warmup
>
> doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
>
> doctrine:cache:clear-query
>
> doctrine:cache:clear-result
>
> rm -rf var/cache/

So the problem is not the cache. I don't want you to solve my problem. But what does this issue mean exactly, and do you have examples of problems that could cause it? I precise I'm not the first developper to work for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you correctly you have removed myEntity.php on purpose and it doesn't exist?

If this is the case it looks like this entity is still being called somewhere in your code or maybe configuration. In dev mode your proxies in the cache folder are only created when you call them. So because this file is being called, Symfony is trying to create the proxy for it.

Comment: Ok so it was what I thought. I'll see later what is the issue in my code but I accept your answer because it help me to understand this error